# Granting service specific capabilities

Tags: linux, services, init-script, capabilities

I have a sm-t365 rooted tablet.
I've created a service in the init.rc file that all it does is create a folder in /data (which requires root), it works if in my service in init.rc i specify **user root**..
From what I understand it means the service has root privileges..
I would like the service not to have root privileges but only specific capabilities for the purpose it needs to accomplish.
I've tries to add certain capabilities from the list in **man capabilities** but if i don't write in the service **user root** it does nothing..
Any ideas?

Comment: Android uses a rather exotic `init`, so it's better to ask at Android StackExchange site.

Comment: @kubanczyk oh, alright. :)